# Check if the entered value is in the range

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to change the background color of the typed row if the entered number is not in the range. The problem I'm facing is currently it is checking only the textbox which is entering due to the on change event attached to the textbox. What I'm looking for is I need to check if any of the textbox value in the row is not in the range.

For example: The first row range is `1 to 4`, I want to check if any of the textbox entered values in the first row is not in the range(1 to 4).

```js
$(document).on("change", "input", function() {
  var enteredValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr')
  var specFrom = parseFloat(parentTr.attr('data-from'));
  var specTo = parseFloat(parentTr.attr('data-to'));
  if (specFrom > enteredValue || specTo < enteredValue) {
    parentTr.css('background-color', 'red');
  } else if (specFrom === enteredValue || specTo === enteredValue) {
    parentTr.css('background-color', 'yellow');
  } else {
    parentTr.css('background-color', 'white');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="1" data-to="4">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>1 to 4</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no1[0]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no2[0]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no3[0]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="5" data-to="10">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>5 to 10</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no1[1]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no2[1]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no3[1]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="10" data-to="15">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>10 to 15</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no1[2]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no2[2]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no3[2]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It should accept the numbers not in the range. Color change is just to notify the user

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include any further thoughts you have; no need to use comments. I would change the code to use classes, then just check whether the row already has an out-of-range class (via `hasClass()`) before adding an in-range class (via `addClass`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your inputs and check then your if-conditions there . Also , you can keep a flag to see if any of the cases meet then you can exit loop without looping further and then assign `bg-color` to your tr.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on("change", "input", function() {
  var cases = ""
  var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr')
  var specFrom = parseFloat(parentTr.attr('data-from'));
  var specTo = parseFloat(parentTr.attr('data-to'));
  parentTr.css('background-color', "white"); //default color
  //loop through inputs
  parentTr.find("input").each(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val())
    if (specFrom > value || specTo < value) {
      cases = "red";
    } else if (specFrom === value || specTo === value) {
      cases = "yellow";
    }
    //if not empty
    if (cases != "") {
      return false; //exit loop
    }
  })
  //change color
  parentTr.css('background-color',
    cases == "" ? "white" : cases);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="1" data-to="4">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>1 to 4</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no1[0]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no2[0]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no3[0]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="5" data-to="10">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>5 to 10</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no1[1]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no2[1]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no3[1]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="10" data-to="15">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>10 to 15</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no1[2]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no2[2]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="text" name="h_no3[2]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to give first priority to red color condition?

Comment: In the first row I tried 4 in the first textbox then the color is yellow which is correct. Then in the next textbox in the same row I entered 5 but it's still in yellow color

Comment: change `if (cases != "") {` to `if (cases != "" && cases != "yellow") {`

Answer (score 0):

Here I created a set of function to determine initial values in "setup"
I then set the `td` background and row background for each 'td' as values change.  I then I fire a trigger to check the row for values and then set the row (`tr`) to the "lowest" level of warning depending upon the `td` values it contains on the observed td's
Note I used green as a "neutral" color instead of white to clearly show the td and row color.

```js
const mything = {
  indicator: {
    warn: "#FFDDDD",
    equal: "#FFFF55",
    neutral: "#DDFFDD"
  }
};

$('#watchme').on("change input", "input[type='number']", function() {
  let v = this.value;
  let enteredValue = parseFloat(v);
  let isNotNumber = Number.isNaN(enteredValue);
  let parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
  let parentTd = $(this).closest('td');
  let specFrom = parseFloat(parentTr.data('from'));
  let specTo = parseFloat(parentTr.data('to'));

  //  console.log(v, typeof isNotNumber,isNotNumber, specFrom, specTo, enteredValue);
  parentTd.data("level", (isNotNumber || enteredValue > specTo || enteredValue < specFrom) ? "warn" :
    (specFrom === enteredValue || specTo === enteredValue) ? "equal" :
    "neutral");
  parentTr.trigger('checkrow');
  let indicatorValue = mything.indicator[parentTd.data("level")];
  parentTd.css('background-color', indicatorValue);
}).on('setup', function() {
  $(this).find("input[type='number']").trigger('change');
}).on('checkrow', 'tr', function() {
  let ov = $(this).find("td.observed_values");
  let r = ov.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('level') == "warn";
    }).length > 0 ? "warn" :
    ov.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('level') == "equal";
    }).length > 0 ? "equal" :
    "neutral";
  $(this).css('background-color', mything.indicator[r]);
}).trigger('setup').trigger('setup');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="watchme" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="1" data-to="4">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>1 to 4</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no1[0]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no2[0]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no3[0]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="5" data-to="10">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>5 to 10</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no1[1]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no2[1]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no3[1]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="set-width1" data-from="10" data-to="15">
    <td>OD</td>
    <td>10 to 15</td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no1[2]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no2[2]" value=""></td>
    <td class="observed_values"><input type="number" name="h_no3[2]" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```